# Why is my Simplex Noise appearing in four columns?

Tags: c#, sfml, simplex-noise

I'm trying to make a `Texture` out of Simplex noise, but it keeps appearing like this regardless of how big or small `scale` is:

[image: Bad simplex noise]

The following code is used to produce the image's color date:

```cs
private Color[,] GetSimplex() {
    Color[,] colors = new Color[800, 600];

    float scale = colors.GetLength(0);

    for (int x = 0; x < 800; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 600; y++) {
            byte noise = (byte)(Noise.Generate(x / scale, y / scale) * 255);
            colors[x, y] = new Color(noise, noise, noise);
        }
    }

    return colors;
}
```

Comment: Could this be a problem with creating the Texture from this Color array and not a problem with filling the array with noise in the first place?  Have you tried mocking this routine with a synthetic output pattern?

Comment: @PatrickHughes If I change `new Color(noise, noise, noise)` to something like `Color.Red`, it works as expected and produces solid red image. So I doubt the issue is with the texture creation library

Comment: I specifically mentioned using a pattern because a single color won't help diagnose this data problem.  The library is creating a texture but you may be giving it data not formatted the way the texture creation library wants.  Only by passing it structured data can you tell how the data is being misinterpreted.  What texture library is being used, how are you calling it with this data?  Have you tried plotting this array pixel by pixel to see what you get?  Lots of debugging left to do =)

Comment: @PatrickHughes I'm using SFML, which takes a `Color[,]` array to create a texture

Comment: try `Color.Argb(255, x/800, y/600, 0)` you should see a continuous UV gradient. That's the test you should have done, and not the uniform `Red`.

Comment: @v.oddou I'll try your suggestion and get back to you with some results by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be one of these three things, or a combination of them (from likely to unlikely)

- There are errors in Noise.Generate()
- X and Y are not random at all and thus poor seed values for the noise
- Truncating the output of Noise.Generate() to a byte reduces entropy. Coincidentally a float has 4 times as much bits as a byte.

Comment: This code uses the C# SimplexNoise library, so i doubt it has any errors in it